# How do I load an image from FirestoreDatabase into ImageView?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to load an image from Firebase database into an ImageView for the user's profile picture.

### What I have tried

I have tried loading the image from Firestore to an ImageView using Glide. My code looks like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) { 
                User user = child.getValue(User.class);
                Glide.with(MapsActivity.this).load(user.getProfilePicture()).error(R.drawable.ic_baseline_person_24).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_person_24).into(profileImage);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {
       throw error.toException();
    }
});
```

However, this isn't working.

My firebase structure is the following:

[image]

Thanks!

```
String url = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user/"+FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid().toString()+"/profilePicture").get().getResult().getValue().toString();
```

Comment: 1) The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both. 2) Never ignore `onCanceled`. At its minimum it should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }` 3) "this isn't working" is really hard to help with, so please provide more debug information. For example, if you put a breakpoint on the first line in `onDataChange` and run in a debugger, does it reach that breakpoint? What does the `snapshot` look like? Is that what you expected?

Comment: You might also take into consideration reading the following article, [How to optimize Firebase Realtime Database calls to improve performance?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-optimize-firebase-realtime-database-calls-to-improve-performance-cc63dad374d5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading the entire `user` node, which contains information for multiple users, so your `snapshot` contains the data for all of those users.

To handle those multiple users, you'll have to loop over `snapshot.getChildren()` in `onDataChange`:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) { //  loop over child snapshots
            User user = child.getValue(User.class);
            Log.i("DB", user.toString());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); //  Never ignore errors
    }
});
```

---

If you know the UID of the user whose image you want to display, you can load just that user with:

```
                                                        //  user to load
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user").child(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        User user = child.getValue(User.class);
        Log.i("DB", user.toString());

    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); //  Never ignore errors
    }
});
```

You no longer need to loop over the `getChildren()` as now the code only loads a single user.

Comment: Sorry, it still isn't working for some reason. The same image shows up on another user's profile. Why is this so?

Comment: The code doesn't index the current user so how do we fetch the user that's currently logged in's profile picture?

Comment: I intentionally did now **display** any of the images, but explained why you're not getting an image. The code in my answer should log the image URLs for all users. If it's fixing the first problem in your code.

Comment: I tried that passing in user.toString() into glide but it didn't work.

Comment: The code is checking for changes in the whole user node. Hence, if you change the picture for one user, log out and then go into another user, their picture changes to that one as well. How do I check the database for the current user logged in's profile picture?

Comment: I added an example for loading the data of a single user.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm confused why we're listening for a data change. What if we want to just directly fetch data from the database without awaiting changes?

Comment: I added the statement I tried at the bottom, and I'm unsure why it's not working.

Comment: The method name is a bit of a misnomer: `onDataChange` immediately fires when you attach it. From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_with_persistent_listeners): "This method is triggered once when the listener is attached and again every time the data, including children, changes."

Comment: Oh, ok. Got it thanks.